# New config maximums for VSphere Update 1

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I'm taking the VCP4 test tomorrow and noticed that some of the Configuration Maximums have changed from base to U1. I'm assuming the test is based on the pre-Update 1 numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on the initial release yes.

Oh and good luck with it, it's a LOT harder than VCP3 - how did you find the course?

Comment: Since I have the VCP3, I didn't need to take the course - assuming I pass today!

Comment: You have to take the course to get the actual VCP4 certification, i.e. you need the course and exam pass.